# How to make the code for Student's Test in R?

Tags: r

I have 50 samples with 10 variables and I have two season for them. So now I would like to use Studen's Test to analysis it but I dont know how to arrange them logically. Could you please help me deal with it. I would like to attach the picture of my data.

[image]

Comment: Why you tagged this question with correlation? You need Student's test or correlation?

Comment: you should like to attach the data using `dput()`. But staring with  `t.test` with the formular option like `t.test(Endpoint ~ season, data = my_data)` would be a good way.

Comment: I need student's test (titan). Sorry

Comment: *"50 samples with 10 variables"*. From the image, I infer at least 67 samples with 15 numeric variables, so it's not really clear. Please reduce your problem with sample code (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) such as `dput(x[1:20,1:6])` and please do not use images (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272).